# Google Cloud Storage XML file Conversion to CSV or JSON format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I am looking into ways of converting XML files from Google Cloud Storage to the JSON or CSV file format and storing it in another GCS bucket.

Anyone would have any suggestions on how to do it? I have been suggested to use DataFlow, but I have no idea how to achieve that since I am not a Python "knower".

I am playing with this sample-data file:
https://fastupload.io/en/8cM24W4JTkYF8dj/file

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Cheers!

I have tried to google different ways how I could achieve this by using the Google Cloud Console - UI but did not find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a simple script which runs on Cloud Function and would convert the XML data to JSON and save it on a different bucket.

First I created a bucket (bucket1), and then created a Cloud Function which [triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) when any object is created in the bucket (bucket1). Then I created another bucket (bucket2) in which the parsed JSON file would be stored.

I don't have much knowledge of Python, so I did it in NodeJS. With some tweaks, you'll be able to do it in Python also. My script looks like this:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const jsonParser = require('xml2json');

exports.xml2json = async (event, context) => {

  //extracting bucket and filename of the object which triggered the function
  const bucketName = event.bucket;
  const fileName = event.name;

  //create new storage object
  const storage = new Storage();

  //getting the contents of the xml file in string format
  const contents = await (await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download()).toString();

  //parsing the XML to JSON
  const parsedJson = jsonParser.toJson(contents);

  //Setting destination bucket and filename
  const destBucketName = process.env.DESTINATION_BUCKET;
  const destFileName = `${fileName.slice(0, -3)}json`;

  //uploading parsed JSON to another bucket
  storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(destFileName).save(parsedJson);

  //printing a log message
  console.log(`File gs://${bucketName}/${fileName} converted and saved to gs://${destBucketName}/${destFileName}`);
};
```

**NOTE: I have put the destination bucket name in the runtime environment varibale in the Cloud Function. You can know more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#setting_runtime_environment_variables).**

The package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "xml-to-json",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^6.8.0",
    "xml2json": "^0.12.0"
  }
}
```

Some reference docs:

- [Downloading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects)
- [Uploading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects-from-memory)
- NPM library used to parse XML to JSON: [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json)

Comment: Hi Avinash,
Thanks for your solution. Could I ask how could I tackle the "failed - reason: socket hang up"? This appears if I am trying to parse a bigger xml file. I have tried to increase the memory to 1GB and Timeout to 540s, but the issue still appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a low-code solution, I would suggest exploring Data Fusion to accomplish the goal you mentioned.

Here you have a good example on how it will work converting XML files to JSON files.

https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-cloud-cdf-to-transform-xml-to-json-6033c785b844

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have tried this approach but it is not optimal in my case.
Would you maybe have some examples of achieving this in Cloud Function, using Python? :)